# Why can't I call ToString() on an interface?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've had different issues re-creating this in a sample console app, so I am very interested to know what's going on.

The original problem is that in my code, I have a class called `ICat` and this class is written in C#

```
public interface ICat
{
  string ToString(CatColour colour);
}
```

In the same assembly, in C#, there is an implementation:

```
public class MagicCat : ICat
{
        public string ToString(CatColour colour)
        {
            return $"I am a {colour} cat";
        }
}
```

This compiles without any problems.

In another assembly, written in VB.NET, I have this code:

```
Dim myCat As ICat = GetCat()
Dim result = myCat.ToString() ' Error on this line
```

This gives a compiler error saying `Argument not specified for parameter 'colour' of 'Function ToString(format As AddressFormat) As String'.`

I tried to recreate this in a C# app, with this code:

```
public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string ToString(CatColour colour)
    {
        return $"I am a {colour} cat.";
    }

    //public string ToString()
    //{
    //    return "I am a cat.";
    //}
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    string ToString(CatColour colour);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAnimal cat = new Cat();

        Console.WriteLine(new Cat().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(new Cat().ToString(CatColour.Red));

        Console.WriteLine(cat.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(cat.ToString(CatColour.Blue));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public enum CatColour
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2
}
```

It compiles and runs, and the output is:

> ConsoleApplication1.Cat 
>   I am a Red cat.
>  
>   ConsoleApplication1.Cat 
>   I am a Blue cat.

(If I uncomment the other ToString() method, the first line is instead `> I am a cat.`)

Which is what I would expect.

I converted the application to VB.NET, expecting to get the original error above, but instead I got this issue:

```
Public Class Cat
    Implements IAnimal
    Public Function ToString(colour As String) As String
        Return "I am a {colour} cat."
    End Function
End Class

Public Interface IAnimal
    Function ToString(colour As String) As String
End Interface
```

`Class 'Cat' must implement 'Function ToString(colour As String) As String' for interface 'IAnimal'`

So what's happening here? Why is VB.NET giving me an error with my interface implementation, and why is my original scenario complaining about no ToString() method that takes no parameters?

---

Edit: I have updated my vb code to this:

```
Public Interface IAnimal
    Function ToString(colour As String) As String
End Interface

Public Class Cat
    Implements IAnimal
    Public Function ToString(colour As String) As String Implements IAnimal.ToString
        Return "I am a {colour} cat."
    End Function
End Class

Sub Main()

    Dim cat As Cat = New Cat()
    Dim icat As IAnimal = New Cat()

    Call cat.ToString()
End Sub
```

I get `Argument not specified for parameter 'colour' of 'Public Function ToString(colour As String) As String'` which is the original problem, that does not occur in the C# code. Any idea why? Cat is an object and thus has a blank `ToString()` method on it.

Comment: you need to explicitly implement your interface method. _Why can't I call ToString() on an interface_  may be because interfaces do not inherit from object.

Comment: In your C# version you have defined to version of 'ToString' method one with parameter and one without any parameter. But in VB version only with parameter version is there. I think you need to override that one also. That means explicit implementation required.

Comment: I guess you could say, why does VB.NET want me to add `ToString()` to the interface in order for it to be callable, whereas C# does not, when `ToString()` is a method of `Object` and `Cat` is an object?

Comment: Note: I would have thought you would want a `$` preceding your returned string, so that the colour is actually replaced in the string (Nice to see someone who knows how to spell colour as well)

Comment: I see that there is a solution to your problem. Although was a valid question, I wouldn't name an interface member as `ToString`, even with different signature, cause could be misleading with the `ToString()` function that everything inherits from `Object`. ;-)

Comment: I think that this is an issue of C# allowing and your usage of Implicit Interface implementations.  If your C# class explicitly implemented the `ToString` method of `IAnimal` like `string IAnimal.ToString(CatColour colour)`, then you would see the same issue in C# as in VB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add a bit more information :

```
Public Class Cat
     Implements IAnimal
     Public OverLoads Function ToString(colour As String) As String Implements IAnimal.ToString
         Return $"I am a {colour} cat."
     End Function
End Class

Public Interface IAnimal
    Function ToString(colour As String) As String
End Interface
```

Or

```
Public Class Cat
     Implements IAnimal
     Public Function MyToString(colour As String) As String Implements IAnimal.ToString
         Return $"I am a {colour} cat."
     End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Aha! That makes the VB.NET part behave as I'd expect. However it doesn't let me call `ToString()` without arguments, even doing `New Cat().ToString()`

Comment: Correct adding overloads to string may have prevented the need to fully call the implements as well...

Comment: Adding `Overloads` appears to have fixed the problem. I am interested to know why this is required in VB.NET

I have no way to add this to the interface in my original problem, as it is written in C# and there is no such keyword.

Comment: It is because you overload a function defined in the base class (object).

Comment: I guess it's a quirk of VB.NET that it needs to be specified. Interesting that it is a breaking problem if you implement an interface in a C# assembly though. In my case, I can edit the referenced assembly to add another `ToString()` implementation and republish the NuGet package, which is still hacky, but if it was a third party method I would not be able to use it correctly in VB.NET. Fancy that.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but this is an article worth reading.http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Comment: Another point to make is that you must implement `ToString()` in all of your C# classes if you plan to use them in VB.NET - it will compile & work in C# but VB will see it in the interface and expect a concrete implementation. This tripped me up.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to declare `Overloads` for the `ToString()` with argument (because you have another base `ToString()` derived from `Object`) and to `Overrides` the `ToString()` without argument which you derived from `Object`:

```
Public Class Cat
    Implements IAnimal
    Public Overloads Function ToString(colour As String) As String Implements IAnimal.ToString
        Return "I am a {colour} cat."
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function ToString()
        Return "I am a cat."
    End Function
End Class

Public Interface IAnimal
    Function ToString(colour As String) As String
End Interface
```

Alternatively, you could create two `ToString()` for the `IAnimal` and you overrides the `ToString()` without argument from `IAnimal` instead of from `Object`

```
Public Class Cat
    Implements IAnimal
    Public Overloads Function ToString(colour As String) As String Implements IAnimal.ToString
        Return "I am a {colour} cat."
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String Implements IAnimal.ToString
        Return "I am a cat."
    End Function
End Class

Public Interface IAnimal
    Function ToString(colour As String) As String
    Function ToString() As String
End Interface
```

Comment: I think this is one is required.

Comment: Can't override it (even though the compiler gives a warning saying it needs overriding) because if I do, I get an error saying there isn't a function to override with that signature.

Comment: Apparently the `Overloads` keyword fixes it but since I've got my interface in a C# assembly there is no way to add the keyword so that VB.NET plays nicely.